# Long numbered list to individual variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, list, variables, split

I have a variable that's storing a numbered list of data in the form of a long string:

```js
var numberedlist = "1. Some info 2. More info 3. Even more info"
```

I want to split each number of the above list into its own variable. For example:

```js
var data1 = "1. Some info"
var data2 = "2. More info"
var data3 = "3. Even more info"
```

I've attempted to use the Split() method, but since each the length of each list item is different, I'm unsure how to use this in order to split this up properly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could split at the `\s` which is followed by a number and a dot (`\d+\.`)

```js
const numberedlist = "1. Some info 2. More info 3. Even more info",
      splits = numberedlist.split(/\s(?=\d+\.)/)

console.log(splits)
```